# Type 'Uint8Array' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators

Tags: typescript, ts-node, metaplex

I'm having these error messages when running a command with ts-node:

````
metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:499:16 - error TS2569: Type 'Uint8Array' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.

499             ...thisSlice.slice(4, 36).filter(n => n !== 0),
                   
metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:502:16 - error TS2569: Type 'Uint8Array' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.

502             ...thisSlice.slice(40, 240).filter(n => n !== 0),```
````

I've already tried updating tsconfig.json target to **es5** and **es2015** and also adding the **downlevelIteration: true** line, but the error keep the same.

What should I do?

Comment: What environments are you targeting that only support ES2015?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just saw this solution on other stack overflow question (changing target to es5/es2015)

Comment: `ts-node` does not automatically pick up your tsconfig.json which is rather unfortunate. You have to manually specify it with `TS_NODE_PROJECT=./path/to/tsconfig.json` before running it.

Comment: @youdateme [The documentation states otherwise](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/tree/v10.7.0#via-tsconfigjson-recommended): "ts-node automatically finds and loads `tsconfig.json`"

Answer (score 0):

> Note that the [`ts-node` README](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/tree/v10.7.0#readme) is fairly exhaustive and covers even more than what I'll detailed here.

Because you haven't provided a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'll show you a self-contained example to demonstrate a working ESM project configuration using [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) and the current [LTS release of Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) (v`16.14.0` at the time I post this answer).

I'll show the contents of each file and detail the important configuration options in comments and/or after the contents:

`./package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-71450483",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node --esm src/main.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  }
}
```

- `devDependencies`:

  - `@types/node`: needed for Node.js APIs
  - `ts-node`: part of your question
  - `typescript`: part of your question
- `type` should be `"module"` [for ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type)
- `scripts.dev`: I added this [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts) to make running the project easier to type on the command line. [The `ts-node` docs section about ES modules](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/tree/v10.7.0#native-ecmascript-modules) explains the requirements for enabling ESM support and shows using a CLI argument to run code in ESM mode: `ts-node --esm src/main.ts`.

  Now, to run your program with `ts-node`, you don't need to remember this syntax: you just need to use the command `npm run dev`.

`./tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Node 16 ESM options
    // Ref: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Node-Target-Mapping#node-16
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2021",

    // Suggestion: strict options for safety
    "strict": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,

    // ts-node overrides these options, but would be useful for actual compilation
    // "declaration": true,
    // "outDir": "dist",
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

See comments above.

- The only *mandatory* `"compilerOptions"` are the ones in the first section under "Node 16 ESM options".
- Your source files will be in the `./src` directory of your project.

> Here's a link to the TSConfig reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig

`./src/main.ts`:

```ts
import {TextDecoder} from 'util';

let u8Array = new Uint8Array([85, 104, 104, 46, 46, 46, 32, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 63]);

u8Array = Uint8Array.from([72, ...u8Array.slice(8, -1)]);
//                             ^^^
// Iterating a Uint8Array using spread syntax,
// just like in the code shown in the error message in your question

const result = new TextDecoder().decode(u8Array);
console.log(result); // logs "Hello world"
```

There's the example code, which uses the same spread syntax on a `Uint8Array`, just like in your question.

---

Now, let's install everything and run it:

```
$ node --version
v16.14.0
```

```
$ npm --version
8.3.1
```

```
$ npm install

added 17 packages, and audited 18 packages in 4s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

```
$ npm run dev

> so-71450483@0.1.0 dev
> ts-node --esm src/main.ts

Hello world
```

Success: The output is as expected with no problems.